# C# Linq expressions can't loop through data results?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, linq-to-entities

I am trying to loop through the IQueryable results data but I get an error at the loop?

```
        var pivot =  from f in query
                     group f by new
                     {
                         Account = f.Account
                     }
                    into g
                     select new
                     {
                         Account = g.Key.Account,
                         Com = g.Where(d => d.Party == "Com").Sum(d => d.Amount),
                     };


        foreach (var item in pivot)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t {item.Account} {item.Com}");
        }
```

I just want to see what is my data after I manipulate it.

The error message I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> "Processing of the LINQ expression
>   'AsQueryable(Where(\r\n    source:
>   NavigationTreeExpression\r\n        Value:
>   default(IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType1, StepTwo>)\r\n
>   Expression: (Unhandled parameter: e6), \r\n    predicate: (d) =>
>   d.Party == \"Com\"))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor'
>   failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
>   information."

Below is the query used to create `query`

```
var query = from inn in db.InputTE.Take(getRecord)
                         join y in db.InputYEM on inn.YPerform equals y.YPerform
                         select new StageTwo
                         {
                             Party = inn.Party,
                             Account = y.Account,
                             Amount = inn.Amount
                         };
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please add it to the question

Comment: Added it, it's at the bottom

Comment: @NoobCoder Please post the code used to create the "query" variable

Comment: @RonanThibaudau I've added it in at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is, essentially, saying that Linq to Entities isn't able adequately translate your expression into SQL. It's going to have to load the entire data set into memory to process. The link in the error message goes into great detail about the problem--it's worth reading.

This error is new in EF Core 3.0. Previously, EF would quietly proceed loading the data set into memory, which often lead to devs writing inefficient queries without realizing it.

Try simplifying the query by moving the `where` clause before the `group by` in your query.

This expression might not be exactly what you need, but I think it's close.

```cs
from f in query
where f.Party == "Com"
group by f.Account into g
select new { Account = g.Key, Com = g.Sum(d => d.Amount) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's much more clear once it's stated. I would have done the f.Pary == "Com" but I need to use more parties at some point